# Why does my JavaScript constructor return default property value instead of the modified one?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

I am working on a small AngularJS application with with Material Steppers.

I have to select items from two sections of the page and return `true` *only if* the items from *both sections* belong to the category with id (`categoryID`) 1.

```
class Controller {
    constructor($mdStepper, validationService) {
        this.$mdStepper = $mdStepper;
        this.isTriggerA = true;
        this.isTriggerB = true;
        this.clickedStepNumber = 0;

        static get $inject() {
            return [
                '$mdStepper',
                'validationService'
            ];
        }

        getCurrentStep() {
          this.steppers = this.$mdStepper('stepper');
          const steps = this.steppers.steps;
          steps.forEach((el, index) => {
            let step = this.steppers.steps[index];
            if (step.isClicked()) {
              this.clickedStepNumber = step.stepNumber;
            }
          });
        }

        checkCategory() {
          this.getCurrentStep();
          if (this.filter.provider) {
            let categoryID = parseInt(this.filter.category.id, 10);

            console.log('Cid: ' + categoryID);

            if (categoryID !== 1) {
              this.isTestPassed = false;
            } else {
              if (parseInt(this.clickedStepNumber, 10) === 1) {
                this.isTriggerA = true;
                console.log('Step: ' + this.clickedStepNumber);
                console.log("A1: " + this.isTriggerA);
                console.log("B1: " + this.isTriggerB);
              }

              if (parseInt(this.clickedStepNumber, 10) === 2) {
                this.isTriggerB = true;
                console.log('Step: ' + this.clickedStepNumber);
                console.log("A2: " + this.isTriggerA);
                console.log("B2: " + this.isTriggerB);
              }

              if (this.isTriggerA === true && this.isTriggerB === true) {
                this.isTestPassed = true;
              } else {
                this.isTestPassed = false;
              }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I also have this service:

```
export default class validationService {
  constructor() {
    this.isTestPassed = true;
  }
}
```

The PROBLEM:

Supose I am in a situation where both my if statements return `false`. From this point, I make a change in the first block (step) so that it returns `true`.

The if in the second block does not "remember" the value returned by the if in the first block. It returns to the value at the top of the constructor.

This means that the folowing block of code

```
if (this.isTriggerA === true && this.isTriggerB === true) {
   this.isTestPassed = true;
} else {
   this.isTestPassed = false;
}
```

returns true to early - before *this.isTriggerA* *and* *this.isTriggerB* are both true.

I need the script to be **aware** of the "state" **of both blocks at all time**.

**Note:** I can not set `isTriggerA` and `isTriggerB` to false at the beginning my code, I need to return true if nothing is selected too.

How can I fix this?

Comment: is this the correct code, because you have declared the functions  getCurrentStep , checkCategory but you haven't executed them also why function declaration is placed in constructor ?

Comment: @abhirathore2006 This is the code I have. I execute `this.getCurrentStep();` inside `checkCategory()`. I execute `checkCategory()`when a button is cliked.

Comment: both the conditions will never be true at the same time

this.clickedStepNumber can either be 1 or 2 can't be both at the same time And if this.clickedStepNumber can have multiple values then write checkCategory logic inside forEach of steps

Comment: Also check if controller constructor is being called on Each click, if so then move variable declaration outside

Comment: initialise values with false instead of true.

Comment: @abhirathore2006 the 2 steps are not in an either this or that relationship. They are in 2 *separate* if statements.

Comment: then just change the default values to false for isTriggerA and isTriggerB

Comment: @abhirathore2006 I prefer that they are true if nu values are hand-piked.

Comment: Code does not compile. It generates a syntax error. Class prototype methods can not be declared inside a class constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the top of your application you are declaring:

```
    this.isTriggerA = true;
    this.isTriggerB = true;
```

That means that the default value for both is true, so if both your if conditions:

```
if (parseInt(this.clickedStepNumber, 10) === 1)
```

And

```
if (parseInt(this.clickedStepNumber, 10) === 2)
```

Are false, the last statement `this.isTriggerA === true && this.isTriggerB === true` will always be true.

To do not execute this by default, set `isTriggerA` and `isTriggerB` to false at the beginning of your code

Since your condition is:

> I have to select items from two sections of the page and return true only if the items from both sections belong to the category with id (categoryID) 1.

There is no sense in to keeping those 2 values as true by default

Comment: I need to return true if nothing is selcted too , that's why those variables are initially true.

Comment: Can you clarify

> Supose I am in a situation where both my if statements return false. From this point, I make a change in the first block (step) so that it returns true.

> The if in the second block does not "remember" the value returned by the if in the first block. It returns to the value at the top of the constructor.

A bit more

Comment: That means: even thou only one of the blocks returns true, it happens what *should* happen if both were true. In other words: the script does not know that one of the blocks is stull false. A solution would be to initialize `isTriggerA` and `isTriggerB` with `false`, but I need them initialized to `true`, as mentioned.

Comment: Well, I guess that the problem is, that when one of the blocks is true... You set isTriggerA or B to true, but you don't set the other one to false (basically you do not set isTriggerA or B to false ever).

Comment: I need the script to be aware of the "state" of both blocks at all time.

Comment: I am not sure I follow the exact logic that you want in your program. You could change the default value to be false and then do something like:
if ((!isTriggerA && !isTriggerB) || (isTriggerA && isTriggerB)) . (a XOR operation), basically or both are false or both are true to pass the test.

Comment: You say "There is no sense in to keeping those 2 values as true by default". What shall I do instead?

Comment: Sorry for coming back late. I think that in my last comment I gave you a hint, using a XOR condition